# extjs warning/error under async function keyword, in VS

Tags: visual-studio, function, extjs, async-await

In Visual Studio Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, I went to FILE, NEW SENCHA PROJECT.  In the MainController.js I added a simple async function.  I am getting a warning from my IDE, a red line under the word function, states "expected ';'".  The code still runs correctly but I am trying to get rid of this error/warning.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
/**
 * This class is the controller for the main view for the application. It is 
specified as
 * the "controller" of the Main view class.
 */
Ext.define('ExtApplication1.view.main.MainController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

  alias: 'controller.main',

  onItemSelected: function(sender, record) {
    Ext.Msg.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure?', 'onConfirm', this);
  },

  onConfirm: function(choice) {
    if (choice === 'yes') {
      //
      foo();
    }
  }
});

async function foo() {
  try {
    console.log(`Got the final result:`);
  } catch (error) {
    //failureCallback(error);

  }
};
```

The red error line is under the function word, next to async foo

Comment: Is it beacuse  of the semi colon at the ene of the function?

Comment: nope... still not working